# How do I return a @declared value in a MySQL Stored Procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, relational-database

I am trying create code that will add a new order to an order list using a stored procedure and am trying to call the procedure as such: CALL test_order(20,12,1, @order);

I keep getting an error around the @order_id/order_id with the code below. I am able to create the stored procedure, but the value won't return.

When using the code below, I get the error:

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@order_id INT)
BEGIN
DECLARE order_id INT;
DECLARE storeID VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE' at line 1

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test_order(IN customerID INT,IN productID INT,IN qty INT, OUT @order_id INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE order_id INT;
    DECLARE storeID VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE staffID INT;
    DECLARE listPrice DECIMAL(10,2);

START TRANSACTION;

/*storeID */
SELECT s.store_id FROM stocks as s INNER JOIN products as p USING(product_id) WHERE p.product_ID = productID ORDER BY s.quantity DESC LIMIT 1 INTO storeID;

/* Next Order */
SELECT max(order_id) + 1 FROM orders INTO @order_id;

/* Staff */
SELECT staff_id FROM staffs where store_id = storeID limit 1 INTO staffID;

/* Order */
INSERT INTO orders VALUES (@order_id, customerID, 1, CURDATE(), ADDDATE(CURDATE(), interval 7 day), NULL, storeID, staffID);

/* Price */
SELECT list_price FROM products WHERE product_id = productID INTO listPrice;

/* Item Row */
INSERT INTO order_items VALUES (@orderId, 1, productID, qty, listPrice, 0);

END //
```

When I take out the @ symbol from the procedure, I'm able to create the procedure, but the order_id is "null". Ex: CREATE PROCEDURE test_order(IN customerID INT,IN productID INT,IN qty INT, OUT order_id INT)

What is wrong with the @order_id?

Comment: `@order_id` is a user defined variable. These are different. Remove the `@` in all locations. Use a local variable since you reuse it. Never fetch the next order_id by max+1. two orders at the same time will fail on you. Use `auto_increment` columns.

Comment: you have to use DELIMITER $$ at the begining of the procedure and also end this procedure by DELIMITER ;

Answer (score 0):

### You have to use DELIMITER $$ first before the procedure and end this procedure by using END$$ and DELIMITER; . I checked and run this procedure on MySQL workbench. now you select your DB, table and check this procedure.

```
 DELIMITER $$

    CREATE PROCEDURE test_order(IN customerID INT,IN productID INT,IN qty INT, OUT order_id INT)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE order_id INT;
        DECLARE storeID VARCHAR(255);
        DECLARE staffID INT;
        DECLARE listPrice DECIMAL(10,2);

    START TRANSACTION;

    /*storeID */
    SELECT s.store_id FROM stocks as s INNER JOIN products as p USING(product_id) WHERE p.product_ID = productID ORDER BY s.quantity DESC LIMIT 1 INTO storeID;

    /* Next Order */
    SELECT max(order_id) + 1 FROM orders INTO @order_id;

    /* Staff */
    SELECT staff_id FROM staffs where store_id = storeID limit 1 INTO staffID;

    /* Order */
    INSERT INTO orders VALUES (@order_id, customerID, 1, CURDATE(), ADDDATE(CURDATE(), interval 7 day), NULL, storeID, staffID);

    /* Price */
    SELECT list_price FROM products WHERE product_id = productID INTO listPrice;

    /* Item Row */
    INSERT INTO order_items VALUES (@orderId, 1, productID, qty, listPrice, 0);

    END$$

    DELIMITER ;
```